# Hacer calculos con datos de otras tablas

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Ayuda por favor, tengo tres tablas(Periodo, Novedades y Liquidacion) con la siguiente informacion, las tablas estan configuradas como clases en ORM Sqlalchemy:
>

```
Periodo:
# con los campos
id_periodo(int)(pk) 
num_periodo (int)
nombre_periodo(varchar)

Novedades:
#campos
id_novedades(int)(pk)
num_periodo(int)(fk)
empleado(int)
dias trabajados(int)
sueldo(float)
horas extras(float)

Liquidacion:
id_liquidacion(int)(pk)
num_periodo (int)(fk)
empleado(int)
dias trabajadosmes(float)
sueldomes(float)
horas extrasmes(float)
```

> Necesito al ejecutar la Clase Liquidacion, y al elijir el numero del Periodo, me inserte los registros de la tabla Novedades en la tabla liquidacion y pueda ejecutar los calculos que necesite. de acuerdo a los parametros establecidos.
>   ejemplo : el campo sueldomes en la tabla liquidacion seria(sueldomes= sueldo/30 * diastrabajados).
>   Agradezco orientacion de antemano gracias.

Comment: Deberías agregar el tipo de cada campo, para saber cuales corresponden a claves foráneas. Podrías pegar la definición de tus modelos?

Comment: La clave esta en que al definir el numero del periodo en Liquidacion me inserte los registros de la tabla Novedades

Comment: Lo mas importante es poder importar los datos de la tabla novedades, lo de los calculos lo defino yo mas facil.